# Thousands of polygons and the IE JavaScript statement limit

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am writing an application which needs to display up to 4000 polygons at once, some with hundreds of coordinates.  Each polygon requires an event for `mouseover`, `mouseout`, and `doubleclick` as well as an infobox label.

I hit a problem initially with the JavaScript statement limit in IE 8. It seems IE restricts JavaScript to processing 5,000,000 VM statements in a single execution block before throwing up an ugly dialog box warning the user of a long-running script (regardless of how quickly the script executes.) I got around this problem by placing JavaScript `"setTimeout"` statements in my code, and breaking the processing into chunks. The script now executes to completion in a reasonable amount of time without hitting the ugly error.

But the problem I am having now comes after my polygons are already built and displayed.  If the user then tries to zoom, the 5,000,000 statement limit is exceeded in IE. But, in this case, the limit is reached during execution of the Google Maps API code, where I have no control and can't put in the setTimeouts or break it into chunks.

In Chrome and Firefox, there is no issue whatsoever, and the polygons load surprisingly quickly, within a few seconds.  Panning and zooming likewise cause no problem.

Things I have tried:

1) reducing the amount of JavaScript statements.  I've tried making my code leaner. But this is actually happening on the redrawing of the polygons within the Google Maps API code, so I'm not sure that would have an effect anyway.

2) reducing the number of points per polygon by requiring less accurate polygons.  This helped a little but didn't fix the problem.

3) Changed the IE "MaxScriptStatements" registry entry to stop IE from using this limitation. It worked, but it's not a practical solution for my application.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: 2 options: 1. Use custom tiles and AJAX calls for the events, like this old V2 demo: http://maps.forum.nu/gm_main.html?lat=44.213710&lon=-100.722656&z=4&mType=5 -- 2. Use only real browsers, (not IE). ;-)

Comment: +1 very interesting question, I didn't know that there is such a limit, I always thought that it depends on time

Comment: I just looked at examples for using custom tiles, and my problem would be in actually creating the tiles. The coordinates are read from a database, and subject to change daily. I don't see how I could get the tiles created, but maybe I am missing something?