# How many data points can the Google Maps API show at one time?

Tags: google-maps

I have a large volume of data (100,000 points). Is it possible to show all the data points at the same time? Someone said that the Google Maps API 3 cannot load more than 3000 data points. Is this true? How many data points can it show at one time?

Comment: AFAIK there is no documented API-based limit(although I read about a [limit of 200](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/Google-Maps-Troubleshooting/mry4ZnsH6YM)), but there may be limits by the environment, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322902/thousands-of-polygons-and-the-ie-javascript-statement-limit

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [this article](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) from the Google Geo APIs team, discussing various strategies to display a large number of markers on a map.

Storing the data using [Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#fusiontables) in particular might be an interesting solution.